# Splitting and Multiplying double will give me wrong values

Tags: java, split, double

I'am trying to multiply A double Variable as time. For example I have 2 hours and 30 minutes. SO the procedure that I have to follow is to multiply 2 with 15 hours for example and then Divide 30 minutes with 60 that is the minutes of the hour and then multiply it with 15. Here is my code:

```
        Double water_time = Double.valueOf(jTextField1.getText());
        String[] seperated = String.valueOf(water_time).split("\\.");
        int[] intseperated = new int[2];
        intseperated[0] = Integer.parseInt(seperated[0]);
        intseperated[1] = Integer.parseInt(seperated[1]);
        int price1 = intseperated[0] * propertiesFile.multiply_water;
        double price2 = (intseperated[1] * propertiesFile.multiply_water) / 60.0D;
        double price = (price1 + price2);
```

My Problem is when iam type 0.10 I get (0.25) that is the correct value but when I type 0.11 I get (2.75) that is wrong. And I cant Understand Why.

I appreciate your time.
 Thank you in advance

Comment: the explanation as well as sampl input /output is very confusing. I dont see in the code anything resembing "multiply 2 with 15 hours " you need to provide better explanation and what are the values for the data from propertiesFile etc

Comment: The 15 is an example inside the configuration file (propertiesFile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the way you're declaring Double water_time.

0.10 becomes Double 0.1 so then you're actually divide 1 by 4, and get mathematically INCORRECT 0.25

0.11 becomes Double 0.11 as you may expect, and you then divide 11 by 4, and mathematically CORRECT 2.75

To fix - split String first , then turn values as Doubles and calculate accordingly.

Working code:

```
    String[] seperated = jTextField1.getText().split("\\.");
    int[] intseperated = new int[2];
    intseperated[0] = Integer.parseInt(seperated[0]);
    intseperated[1] = Integer.parseInt(seperated[1]);
    int price1 = intseperated[0] * propertiesFile.multiply_water;
    double price2 = (intseperated[1] * propertiesFile.multiply_water) / 60.0D;
    double price = (price1 + price2);
```

Comment: I Think its ok Now Thanks a lot. But I get an error. Do you know what causes it? 
http://prntscr.com/jcch9j

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to divide the decimal value by 60 and then multiply of by 15. But what you have done is first multiplied by 15, then divided the whole answer by 60.

```
double price2 = (intseperated[1] / 60.0D) * propertiesFile.multiply_water;
```

Comment: I change it on what you send me but I still Get wrong Value.